# JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).onclick is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner and I got an error on my JavaScript.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function(){
    $(".widgetselecterbtn").onclick(function(){
        var index = $(".widgetselecterbtn").index(this);
        $('.itemselected').addClass('hide');
        $('.itemselected').eq(index).removeClass('hide');
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="wighet">
    <li><div><i class="fa fa-header fa-lg"></i><br><a class="widgetselecterbtn">heading</a></div></li>
    <li><div><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i><br><a  class="widgetselecterbtn">text</a></div></li>
    <li><div><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-lg"></i><br><a class="widgetselecterbtn">Youtube</a></div></li>
    <li><div><i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-lg"></i><br><a class="widgetselecterbtn">quate</a></div></li>
    <li><div><i class="fa fa-link fa-lg"></i><br><a class="widgetselecterbtn">link</a></div></li>
    <li><div><i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-lg"></i><br><a class="widgetselecterbtn">image</a></div></li>
    <li><div><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i><br><a class="widgetselecterbtn">Twitter</a></div></li>
</ul>
<div class="ItemWidget01 itemselected hide">                 
</div>
<div class="ItemWidget01 itemselected hide">            
</div>
<div class="ItemWidget01 itemselected hide">            
</div>
<div class="ItemWidget01 itemselected hide">                 
</div>
<div class="ItemWidget01 itemselected hide">                
</div>
<div class="ItemWidget01 itemselected hide">                
</div>
<div class="ItemWidget01 itemselected hide">                  
</div>
```

The error is

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).onclick is not a function

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 25):

`onclick` is not a jQuery function. You should use `click` instead.

```
$(".widgetselecterbtn").click(function() {
    //do your task here
});
```